# How to display the sum in this graph. I have the same year in my database (2012) How can i add those 2 data? And display automatically in graph?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to display the sum in this graph. I have the same year in my database (2012) How can i add those 2 data? And display automatically in graph? This is the codes of my sample:

```
<?php 

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$query = "SELECT * FROM account";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $chart_data .= "{ year:'".$row["year"]."', profit:".$row["profit"].", 
    purchase:".$row["purchase"].", sale:".$row["sale"]."}, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    config = {
        data: [<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
        xkey: 'year',
        ykeys: ['profit', 'purchase', 'sale'],
        labels: ['Profit', 'Purchase', 'Sale'],

        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        behaveLikeLine: true,
        resize: true,
        pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
        pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
        lineColors: ['gray','red']
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I want to display only one year but the sum of both same year with percentage. Is it possible?